# Не работает hover у корзины

Tags: html, css

```
 <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn  btn-block btn-lg dropdown-toggle">  <a class="shop"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <span id="cart-total"><?php echo $text_items; ?></span></button>

.shop {
    background-color: #1E73BE;
    display: inline-block;
padding-left: 12px;
padding-right: 12px;
}

.shop:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
.fa-shopping-bag {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.fa-shopping-bag:hover {
    color: purple;
}
```

http://sitehero.us/

Comment: а как он должен работать ? а то у нас ховер и на иконку и на ссылку.Напишите более детально

Comment: нужно чтобы иконка менялась при наведении. уже и дивом и спаном и ссылкой делал, ничего

Answer (score 0):

но думаю что так будет нормально

```
     .shop {
        background-color: #1E73BE;
        display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    }

    .shop:hover {
        background-color: white;
    }
    .fa-shopping-bag {
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .shop:hover .fa-shopping-bag {
        color: purple;
    }
```

Comment: Это процитированный мой код и что?

Comment: он подправлен, почитайте внимательно у вас в коде написано чтоб цвет менялся при наведении на иконку, а чтоб она менялась при наведении на спан нужно прописать .shop:hover .fa-shopping-bag

Comment: Все равно ничего не происходит :(

Comment: попробуйте вместо shop -> btn написать, просто вы наводите на button а не на тег а, можете лутше даный клас (shop) прописать для button

Comment: а так изначально конструкция немного странная, лутше б по другому ее написать.  не button а div например

Comment: не не помогает. А дивом кнопку делать это как? это кнопка же у нее есть действие!

Comment: интересно напишите в файле stylesheet.css линейка 300 змените на .shop:hover .fa-shopping-bag {
    color: purple;
} и все работает. даный файл думаю знаете где находиться